# Which hook should be used to add an action containing a redirect?

Tags: plugin-development, redirect, hooks, actions, init

I want to build a plugin that grabs certain url params from the query string to build a new query string for the same page. I'm following the excellent the Professional WordPress Plugin Development book, but I'm not sure which hook to use for this action. Here is my action function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'tccl_redirect' );
function tccl_redirect() {
    header ( "Location: http://www.mysite.com/$mypage?$newparam=$newvalue" );
?>
```

Which hooks are suitable for header redirects?

Comment: Do you actually want to change the final URL or just the variables used in WP_Query?

Comment: The code you've posted would basically redirect every page, is that what you want? Under what conditions should this redirection occur? **NOTE:** I've +1'ed kaiser anyway, `template_redirect` would also be my suggestion.

Comment: scribu, I want to change final url and query string.

Comment: t31os, I simplified my code for the question. The real thing contains more conditions.

Comment: What was the outcome? Mark a solution pls.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like kaiser answered `template_redirect` hook is indeed appropriate for redirects.

Also you should use [`wp_redirect()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) function, rather than setting header.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, wouldn't mind knowing why wp_redirect is preferable, here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12944/why-is-wp-redirect-preferable-to-a-standard-php-header-redirect

Answer (score 25):

I'd say `template_redirect`. But take a look at the [Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

### Example

Don't forget to `exit()` on redirect.

```
/**
 * This example redirects everything to the index.php page
 * You can do the same for the dashboard with admin_url( '/' );
 * Or simply base the redirect on conditionals like 
 * is_*() functions, current_user_can( 'capability' ), globals, get_current_screen()...
 * 
 * @return void
 */
function wpse12535_redirect_sample() {

    exit( wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) ) );

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse12535_redirect_sample' );
```

Answer (score 13):

But i would say this example from [kaiser](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/385/kaiser) cannot working, because after an redirect this hook **template_redirect** works again and again, you will have an **endless forwarding** !

Better is to check, if you're already on the homepage, like this:

```
function wpse12535_redirect_sample() {

    $current_url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $site_url = get_bloginfo('siteurl') . "/";

    if($current_url != $site_url)       
      exit( wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ) ));    

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse12535_redirect_sample');
```

Works for me fine. Any suggestions? Regards!